# Prove lim sequence

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to pose the following problem that I have some doubts about how to fix it because I get to a point where the algebraic process is complicated to settle and I can not concretqr the demonstration, so I would ask if there is an algebraic trick so that the expression is more friendly, the problem is this.

$$  \lim \nolimits_{n\to \propto }\sqrt[n]{(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1} )^{\frac{n^{2}+1}{2n} }} =\sqrt[4]{e^{5}} $$

I will be very grateful to your comments and suggestions.

Comment: It would be good to edit  the question to make the answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit is meant to be $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n}}$, then we can write

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{n}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(1+\frac{2}{n})^{n}}{(1-\frac{1/2}{n})^{n}}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}=\left(\frac{e^2}{e^{-1/2}}\right)^{1/2}\cdot1^{0}=e^{5/4}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{2n+4}{2n-1}=1+\frac{5}{2n-1}$.

Now express our limit (**without** the $n$-root part, please see the  remark below) as the limit of
$$\left(\left(1+\frac{5}{2n-1}\right)^{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n(2n-1)}}.$$
Now you can finish.

**Remark:** There is a typo in the question. If we want to take the $n$-th root, then we want the exponent to be $\frac{n^2+1}{2}$. It we want an $n$-th root **and** exponent $\frac{n^2+1}{2n}$ then the limit is $1$. But if the exponent is supposed to be $\frac{n^3+1}{2n}$, then the $n$-th root is OK, and the limit is right.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is mistake. If it is really $n$th square, then you shall get this.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n}}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{2n+4}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{5}{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\dfrac{5}{2n-1}\right)^{2n-1}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2(2n-1)}}=(e^5)^0=1$$

I checked it using MAPLE. It also gives $1$ as the limit. Sorry for not writing a comment first, but I am quite new to the site and have not unlocked this feature yet.

Comment: Ty for maple sugerence

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it? I cannot understand what you want to say here.

Comment: Thank you for MAPLE jeje :).

Comment: Ah, it is okay now :D